# CAS 4 , AuthenticationViaFormAction errors exceptions does not show

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, jasig

In AuthenticationViaFormAction ,   public final Event submit

i purposely triggered

```
logger.warn("Invalid login ticket {}", providedLoginTicket);
messageContext.addMessage(new MessageBuilder().code("error.invalid.loginticket").build());
return newEvent(ERROR);
```

however, in login page it does not show "You cannot attempt to re-submit a form that has been submitted already." this exceptions...

is it bug?

Comment: Since someone got reply, then i post the workable code to share.
new MessageBuilder().error().code("authenticationFailure.InvalidCaptcha").arg("").defaultText("authenticationFailure.InvalidCaptcha").build() , this should work and return message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new MessageBuilder().error().code("authenticationFailure.InvalidCaptcha").arg("").de‌​faultText("authenticationFailure.InvalidCaptcha").build() , this should work and return message.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange! This is the exact line of code taken from CAS 4.1: https://github.com/Jasig/cas/blob/master/cas-server-core/src/main/java/org/jasig/cas/web/flow/AuthenticationViaFormAction.java#L159.

I assume it should work. Would you mind posting your question on the CAS users mailing list?

Comment: hi jleleu, where is website of CAS users mailing  list? please advice me, thanks.

Comment: i get it from from cas4 release, because i need to customize it. and then i found it doesnt work. i means i purposely throw exception, but it doesnt throw message to front end.

Comment: It's a google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/jasig-cas-user.

Comment: almost give up that platform, whenever i post or reply, keep sending me "Sorry, but WiscList ListManager did not find your email address" , https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jasig-cas-user/2-IJ5ehKkZo

Comment: I guess you first need to subscribe using the apporpriate mail: http://jasig.github.io/cas/Mailing-Lists.html.